# Would a griffon be a better mount than a horse

Tags: pathfinder-1e

In a game I'm currently in, my character is being given the option to stay with horse as a mount or move on and get a griffon (through the use of the monstrous mount feat). The game will be taking place underground for the next 12 weeks and i was wondering which would make a better mount??

Comment: This isn't a forum - we don't deal well with opinion-based topics. To keep this question alive, you should specify what you trying to accomplish with the mount.  Are there certain characteristics, constraints, or goals we need to know about?

Comment: @indigochild: Well, "underground" would seem to be an important constraint.

Comment: Closing this as primarily opinion-based seems a bit weird, in a game where a mount can easily be measured in statistics. Simply comparing it's health, AC, carrying capacity and ability to fit through tunnels could have lead to a completely unbiased result on which one is better.

Comment: Is the question really "is a griffon better than a horse" (obvious) or "is a griffin better enough than a horse to use my feat slot on?"  If you already spent the slot and just have both a horse and a griffin in the garage ready to go, then I agree this is an objective slam-dunk question.  It's still better to state more requirements, because in the case both had pros and cons and one choice wasn't just the other choice++, you'd get the close again till you stated some values that would help us estimate the tradeoffs for you.

Answer (score 5):

### The Griffon

The [griffon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/monstrous-mount) has basically every advantage of over a horse. Specifically:

**Darkvision**
One of the most inconvenient things about being underground is managing light. You can carry torches, but having darkvision is ideal.  The horse has low-light vision, but the griffon has the far superior darkvision.

**Combat Ability**
Generally, a mount isn't something that attacks on it's own. You ride it around, hoping it doesn't get killed.  A griffon gains a +4 AC bonus, as well as the rake and pounce special abilities, which make it more useful.

**Some Other Things**
Griffons also have a fly speed, the scent special ability, and can understand Common.  All of these are much better than a horse.

### The Downside

RAW, a cavalier's mount can only be from the list of animals specified in the class's description.  You can take the [Monstrous Mount](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/monstrous-mount) feat to add griffon to that list at level 4.

You have to expend a feat to get the griffon mount, but it is still far superior to the horse.